# Microsoft.ml cannot find the csv file even though its in my file directory

Tags: c#, ml.net

i know this seems very dumb but for some reason the text file cannot be found.

var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile("./housing.csv", hasHeader: true,
separatorChar: ',');
when ever i run this code the vs console gives this error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'File or directory does not exist at path: ./housing.csv '

Comment: is it in /debug folder?

Comment: Might have to set it to copy if it’s newer on the file properties in VS

Answer (score 0):

The applications working directory might not be what you expect.

try adding:

```
string dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var data = context.Data.LoadFromTextFile(dir + "\\housing.csv", hasHeader: true, separatorChar: ',');
```